# Reachability hangs my app when network is too weak

Tags: ios

Am using reachability api to check network connection before a service request.Sometimes when the network is too weak it hangs my app and after some time I get the status.If I switch off my WiFi immediately i get the status and when network is proper ,then also I get the status instantly but when network is weak(My assumption)its doesn't give the status instantly and as a result gives the user the assumption that the app is freezed and after sometime gives the status that the network is down.How can I tell the user that app is not freezed but it is checking for reachability?

```
 InternetConnection *ic=[[InternetConnection alloc] init];
 if([ic connectedToNetwork])
 {
 //do some request
 }
 else
 {
 UIAlertView *alert=[[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@""
            message:@"Network down"
            delegate:nil
                                                            cancelButtonTitle:AGLocalizedString(@"key_ok",nil)
                                                otherButtonTitles:nil];
            [alert show];
}


//check internet connection code
- (BOOL) connectedToNetwork{
    Reachability* reachability = [Reachability reachabilityWithHostName:@"google.com"];
    NetworkStatus remoteHostStatus = [reachability currentReachabilityStatus];

    if(remoteHostStatus == NotReachable)
    {
        isInternet =FALSE;
    }
    else if (remoteHostStatus == ReachableViaWWAN)
    {
        isInternet = TRUE;
    }
    else if (remoteHostStatus == ReachableViaWiFi)
    { isInternet = TRUE;

    }
    return isInternet;
}
```

Comment: Give the timeout option for the request?

Comment: how do i give the timeout option?

Answer (score -1):

It looks like you are calling a function `synchronously` that should only be called asynchronously. That's something you should never, ever do - you saw the results.

You need an object storing the currently known status, which is connected, not connected, or unknown. Then you create a`Reachability` object, check its status in the background, and ask it to observe changes as well.

And make sure you test this properly and don't give the user a barrage of alerts; they won't be pleased.

Comment: How can I call it asynchronously?